# Denied access to an ext4 partition after doing a `mount -a` command

Tags: mount, fstab

I have installed a second internal hard drive. I have read help various help files on mounting via fstab file. After running the `mount -a` command. The partition is mounted /mnt/films. But when i select the folder i can't do anything. I'm informed that i'm not the root user, and have no permissions. (I am a complete beginner learning mode one step at a time)
ubuntu oneric

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc                                       /proc  proc  nodev,noexec,nosuid  0  0  
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=4810412d-43db-477a-b6f2-8f2948924d90  /      ext4  errors=remount-ro    0  1  
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=967bd3d5-32e5-4f20-9095-446047353d21  none   swap  sw                   0  0  
#

# /dev/sdb1 is Seagate Barracuda 2TB
UUID=a35d1e8d-4461-4e33-abf7-edea029d7ae5 /mnt/Films    ext4    rw,sync,user     0 0
```

Comment: Suggested edit: Corrected typo in title and added tag for fstab

Answer (score 2):

You should create the folder `/mnt/films` using the command (in a `terminal`):

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/films
```

Then you need to change permissions so that you have read access to the folder:

```
sudo chown root:users /mnt/films
```

This allows group use by the `users` group which your logged in user should be a member of (it will be as standard). So make sure that the group permissions include read and write:

```
sudo chmod g+rw /mnt/films
```

If ther are folders and/or files already on the drive, you may need to adjust their ownership and permissions too.

I assume that you have formatted the drive as `ext4`? By default it probably came formatted as FAT32.

Comment: Also, if you are just starting out with Ubuntu, you are probably better off using the latest release (12.04) if you can.

Comment: Thanks Julian. I will read up on the chmod command, and it options. I did format the drive as ext4. Was I Wrong? Can you point out what mistake I made in editing the fstab file. I will install ubuntu 12.04 after I have learnt how to add additional drives in the fstab. Will keep you informed.

Comment: One question - how big is the drive? There can be issues with drives >2.1TB. Other than that, the fstab entry looks ok & ext4 is fine so nothing there. That's why I kind of assume it must be a permissions issue.

Comment: Hi Justin, I have installed ubuntu 12.04. I have edited the fstab file, and have my 2tb internal sata drive mounting in /mnt/films. When i go in to the directory of films. There is a folder call lost+found, and it only has user permissions drwx------ 2 root. To gain access rights/have the same access rights as the root. Using chmod, do i need to make changes to access rights of the group of this file eg. drwxrwx---. My aim is to have a directory on that 2tb drive that i can store all my films. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Julian, sorry for getting your name wrong in my previous post. Such a massive learning curve for me and my brain. I have re read your answer. Which has answer my question. Sorry.